# Ocaml: usage of match with

Tags: match, ocaml

I'm trying to write some code in ocaml that parses the following c code for predefined functions

```
  main {
  x = function1(3);
  x = function2(x,2);
}
```

So here is my ocaml code:

```
match expr with 
    |Bool(b) ->( match b with
          |true -> (*do things*)
          |false -> (*do things*) )
          
    
      |Call(f, args) ->( match f with
          | function1(x) -> (*do things with x*)
          | function2(x,n) -> (*do things with x and n*) 
          |_ -> failwith "not implemented yet " )
```

For the time being, let's assume the language I'm parsing only has two functions, I would like to retrieve the arguments in the C code in order to use them in my ocaml program but I get a syntax error at the line containing the match with sth()

Removing the parentheses and the arguments make the program run but this is not what I want, I need to arguments...

I don't understand what is wrong with my matching could someone please explain the right syntax to me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you give here isn't legal OCaml, as there is no such pattern as `function1(x)`. This might be your problem, or it might not. It would be better if you gave a self-contained example and showed the exact error messaage.

Comment: thx for your comment,it helped! I kind of managed to solve my problem thanks to it and to chimrod's answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern matching only match type constructors.

The first thing to do is to write down the type you want to match :

```ml
type typ =
  | Bool of bool
  | Function1 of int
  | Function2 of int * int
```

Then your fonction will look like this one (combining all the differents case inside a single one match case):

```ml
let eval
  : typ -> unit (* The function signature *)
  = fun t ->
    match t with
    | Bool true -> print_endline "true"
    | Bool false -> print_endline "false"
    | Function1 number -> print_endline (string_of_int number)
    | Function2 (n1, n2) -> print_endline (string_of_int (n1 + n2))
```